# Retreive exhaustive list of libraries and their versions using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, static-libraries

I am doing a legal audit of an application and I need to retrieve the following

1. Linked libraries
2. Library versions
3. Library link types (ie. statically vs. dynamically)

I have been told I should go through the CMakeLists.txt file(s) and look for occurrences of *find_package*, *find_library*, or *pkg_check_modules*. Furthermore, I have been told that this is preferable to using `ldd`.

Is there any way to automate this? It is a very tedious and time consuming process to do everytime a new build is released.

Comment: You could probably automate it by setting up a project and then using the following API to query the information.  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html